# Spigot | PersistantDataContainer() says Cannot Resolve

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, bukkit

may be a stupid question, but there is a message calle `cannot resolve` if i use `getPersistentDataContainer()` in my method. How can i fix this?

```
    private ItemStack createItem(String name, ArrayList<String> lore, Material mat, String itemfunc, int amount) {

    ItemStack iStack = new ItemStack(mat, amount);
    ItemMeta iMeta = iStack.getItemMeta();
    iMeta.getPersistentDataContainer().set(this.ITEMFUNC, PersistentDataType.STRING, itemfunc);
    iMeta.setDisplayName(name);
    iMeta.setLore(lore);
    iStack.setItemMeta(iMeta);


    return iStack;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
        <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
                <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Only if you use the VaultAPI, you have to exclude `org.bukkit`. So that we can use it from the original dependency